# Concrete5 - how to get page_list edit screen to read values in custom fields

Tags: concrete5

### 1. Setup

We've added two layout dropdown fields to the page_list block's edit screen by overriding:

- db.xml
- page_list_form.php
- Adding the fields to the view

---

### 2. In db.xml we've added:

```
<field name="gridSize" type="C" size="255">
</field>
<field name="gridPaddingStyle" type="C" size="255">
</field>
```

---

### 3. In page_list_form.php

**We've added the slect fields to the block edit screen like this:**

```
  <div class="ccm-block-field-group">
    <h2><? echo t('Grid layout')?></h2>

    <p><? echo t('Grid size')?></p>
      <?php
          $gridSize = array(
          '1up' => 'grid-list-item-single grid-unit-1',
          '2up' => 'grid-unit-2',
          '3up' => 'grid-unit-3',
          '4up' => 'grid-unit-4',
          '5up' => 'grid-unit-5',
          '6up' => 'grid-unit-6'
          );

          if (is_array($gridSize)) :
      ?>
      <select name="gridSize" id="selectGridSize">
          <? foreach ($gridSize as $gridItem => $value) : ?>
          <option value="<?= $value ?>" <?php if ($gridSize == $value) { ?> selected <?php } ?>>
          <?= $gridItem ?>
          </option>
          <? endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <? endif; ?>

      <p><? echo t('Grid padding style')?></p>
      <?php
          $gridPaddingStyle = array(
          'Padding' => '',
          'No padding' => 'grid-no-padding',
          'Hairline' => 'grid-hairline'
          );

          if (is_array($gridPaddingStyle)) :
      ?>
      <select name="gridPaddingStyle" id="selectPaddingSize">
          <? foreach ($gridPaddingStyle as $gridPaddingStyleItem => $value) : ?>
          <option value="<?= $value ?>" <?php if ($gridPaddingStyle == $value) { ?> selected <?php } ?>>
          <?= $gridPaddingStyleItem ?>
          </option>
          <? endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <? endif; ?>
  </div>
```

---

### 4. In the view.php we've added:

```
$gridSize = $controller->gridSize;
$gridPadding = $controller->gridPaddingStyle;
```

Which obviously pulls the data out of the database for use when we output the markup.

---

Everything works great except when we come to re-edit the block - essentially the values previously set for our custom fields don't get read and the dropdowns revert back to the first items in the select lists.

---

### 5. Question

How do we get the page_list edit screen to read the values previously set in the database?

---

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated (sorry, can't work out how to get syntax highlighting working - wish the markdown was the same ad Github issues).

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're overwriting the variables in your edit view `$gridSize = array(...)` just before you're trying to access them, you can probably fix it by changing those array variable names to something semantic like "grid_size_options".

If that doesn't work, you can use `$this->set` to pass variables to the view from the controller `edit` method. Your edit method would look something like this:

```php
public function edit()
{
    $this->set('grid_size', $this->gridSize);
    $this->set('grid_padding_style', $this->gridPaddingStyle);
}
```

and then your edit view can just magically access `$grid_size` and `$grid_padding_style`.

```php
 <select name="gridPaddingStyle" id="selectPaddingSize">
     <?php 
     foreach ($gridPaddingStyle as $gridPaddingStyleItem => $value) {
         ?>
         <option value="<?= $value ?>" <?= $grid_padding_style == $value ? 'selected' : '' ?> >
             <?= $gridPaddingStyleItem ?>
         </option>
         <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Korvin, you're absolutely right. Unfortunately, we're confused about how to work with alternate variable names (like "grid_size_options") and still pull the correct field out of the database - php is not our specialty! Will try overriding the controller as suggested.

Comment: The options are not coming from the database, you're setting it in your example `$gridSize = array(`, just change that variable name and you will not be overwriting it anymore. You should reread my full comment because it answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks Korvin - I think you would be surprised at how many times I read your answer! It all works thank you but I still don't understand how it grabs the items for the select list array initially - but then uses the database if something is already set? is that what this does? ```<option value="<?= $value ?>" <?= $gridSize == $value ? 'selected' : '' ?>>```

Comment: The options aren't coming from the database, you're only saving the _one option that people choose_. Look at lines 6-13 in that link I provided, you are giving it a list of options.

Comment: But at some point a selection is saved to the database - right? And this the line that compares what is in the database and selects it from the list? ```<option value="<?= $value ?>" <?= $gridSize == $value ? 'selected' : '' ?>>```

Comment: Yes. If you select and save the first option, when `$value` is "1up", that option will be automatically selected.